# Angular editable config

Tags: angular, typescript, config

I need to make a config file which can be modified after app build. I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2018/03/01/angular-how-to-editable-config-files/)

Now I have `config-init.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Response } from "@angular/http";
import { UriConfig } from "../shared/models/uri-config.model";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigInitService {

    static settings: UriConfig;

    load(): Promise<void> {
        const file = 'assets/config/uris.json';
        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get(file).toPromise().then((response: Response) => {
                ConfigInitService.settings = <UriConfig>response.json();
                console.log('Loading config');
                resolve();
            }).catch((err: any) => {
                reject(`Could not load file "${file}": ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
            });
        });
    }

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) {
    }
}
```

In App module

```
providers: [
        ...
        ConfigInitService,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: () => initializeApp,
            deps: [ConfigInitService],
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}

export function initializeApp(uriConfig: ConfigInitService) {
    console.log('app init');
    return () => uriConfig.load();
}
```

According to console the factory is being used when app inits, however there is no console message from `load` function as well ass no working service which depends on these settings.

Comment: If you check in the network tab of the browser developer tools, can you it making a request for that file?

Comment: load function even is not invoced ever

Comment: Check the answer below, that should solve your problem

Comment: Load function is not call but do 'app init' appear in your console? It can help to see when the problem occur, if the 'app init' is not call then you have a problem inside your App Module, if it appear then it's inside your Load method where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UriConfig } from "../shared/models/uri-config.model";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigInitService {

    static settings: UriConfig;

    load() {
    }

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) {
        this.http.get('assets/config/uris.json').subscribe((file: UriConfig) => {
            ConfigInitService.settings = file;
        });
    }
}
```

As my investigation showed the service is being initialized meanwhile function isn't invoked, therefore I've placed simple http GET request in constructor and achieved the result I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the function to `useFactory` through `initializeApp` function however you might be interested sending the data from `load` function. You should make the small correction in your `initializeApp` function as -

```
export function initializeApp(uriConfig: ConfigInitService) {
    console.log('app init');
    return uriConfig.load(); //<-- return the value from load function.
}
```

Comment: No, it will return the function definition instead of calling and getting the value from it.

Comment: If you have read the code you could notice that I'm not returning anything but just assigning the result of promise to the static variable

Comment: Now you are encountered with next issue which is related `ConfigInitService` dependency. ConfigInitService` is not being injected or initialized in factory function `initializeApp`.

Comment: Why isn't it injected meanwhile it looks like injected via function parameter? Also it's specified in deps

Answer (score 0):

Can you move the promise section inside function.

```
load(): Promise<void> {
        const file = 'assets/config/uris.json';
    return () => {
        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get(file).toPromise().then((response: Response) => {
                ConfigInitService.settings = <UriConfig>response.json();
                console.log('Loading config');
                resolve();
            }).catch((err: any) => {
                reject(`Could not load file "${file}": ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
            });
        });
      }
    }
```